# Can't figure out why material toolbar is being pushed down on smaller resolutions

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5p7xog?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.html

I'm altering one of the sidenav examples found on the Angular material page. The sidenav works perfectly on larger resolutions, but once you scale down, the header pops down leaving whitespace above it. Could anyone explain what's happening here and a possible solution?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its happening because you are explicitly setting 56px as margin in mobile view.

```
  <mat-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-container"
                         [style.marginTop.px]="mobileQuery.matches ? 56 : 0">
```

Which is fine, but since the position of the element is changed to fixed. You need to set the top to 0 otherwise it will take the margin-top.

Modify your toolbar style to this

```
.example-is-mobile .example-toolbar {
  position: fixed;
  /* Make sure the toolbar will stay on top of the content as it scrolls past. */
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
}
```